encode ngx-angular-query-builder-query
i am using ngx-angular-query-builder
i need a javascript methods
that decode a string expression and return a rulebuilder json
this is the string example
(entity.sub148 == "foo" || entity in "bar")
object should be like this
{
    "name": "",
    "type": "Asset",
    "condition": "or",
    "rules": [
        {
            "field": "entity.sub148",
            "operator": "==",
            "value": {
                "type": "const",
                "content": "dsq"
            }
        },
 {
            "field": "entity ",
            "operator": "in",
            "value": {
                "type": "const",
                "content": "dsqd"
            }
        }, 
    ]
}

lets hardcode rule.value.type to be always 'const'
also expression can also be complex like this
(entity.sub148 EQUAL "foo" AND entity EQUAL "xxx" AND (entity2.sub EQUAL "xxx" OR (entity EQUAL "xxx" OR entity EQUAL "xxx") OR entity EQUAL "xxx"))
it should be handled
if the result can't be handled please return undefined or null
i used this two method to convert json to string
  buildExpression(rule: Rule): string {
    if (!rule) {
      return '';
    }
    if (rule.condition && rule.rules) {
      const subExpressions = rule.rules
        .map((subRule) => this.buildExpression(subRule))
        .filter(Boolean);
      if (subExpressions.length === 0) {
        return '';
      }

      if (subExpressions.length === 1) {
        return subExpressions[0];
      }

      const logicalOperator = rule.condition.toUpperCase();
      return '(' + subExpressions.join(` ${logicalOperator} `) + ')';
    }

    if (rule.field && rule.operator && rule.value) {
      return `${rule.field} ${rule.operator} ${this.getValueAsString(
        rule.value
      )}`;
    }

    return '';
  }

  getValueAsString(value: BuilderVariable): string{
   
    if (value.type === 'const') {
      return `"${value.content}"`;
    }
    return value.content;
  }

i need the way back
now i just need the way back
